# GSON - получение числового значения

Tags: java, json, gson

Есть такой код для получения значения-строки:

```
json = response.toString();
JsonObject statsObj = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement stats = statsObj.get("status");
String status = stats.toString();
System.out.println(status);
```

Значение `status` - строка. При попытке получить любое другое числовое значение, получаю ошибку `NullPointerException`:

```
response.toString();
JsonObject statsObj = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement stats = statsObj.get("last_battle_time");
int lbt = stats.getAsInt();
System.out.println(lbt);
```

Подскажите, как изменить код парсера для числовых значений?

---

Структура JSON

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "meta": {
        "count": 1
    },
    "data": {
        "36791942": {
            "last_battle_time": 1435324597,
            "account_id": 36791942,
            "created_at": 1419093115,
            "updated_at": 1436952967,
            // ... другие поля...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы получаете NPE, когда вызываете методы `stats.getAs*()` ?

Comment: Да. Если значение элемента строка -то все нормально

Comment: Если при вызове `stats.getAsInt()`  вы получаете NPE, значит `stats == null`, значит `statsObj.get("last_battle_time")`  вернул `null`. Покажите значение переменной `json`.

Comment: @Nofate http://pastebin.com/qvGcuk1Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На верхнем уровне в вашем json нет поля `last_battle_time`, поэтому вы и получаете `null`. Вам  сначала нужно из `statsObj` вытащить `data`, затем `36791942` и уже из него `last_battle_time`.

```
String json = "{\n" +
        "    \"status\": \"ok\",\n" +
        "    \"meta\": {\n" +
        "        \"count\": 1\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    \"data\": {\n" +
        "        \"36791942\": {\n" +
        "            \"last_battle_time\": 1435324597,\n" +
        "            \"account_id\": 36791942,\n" +
        "            \"created_at\": 1419093115,\n" +
        "            \"updated_at\": 1436952967\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}";

int id = 36791942;
JsonObject statsObj = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject dataObj = statsObj.getAsJsonObject("data");
JsonObject playerObj = dataObj.getAsJsonObject(Integer.toString(id));
long lbt = playerObj.get("last_battle_time").getAsLong();
System.out.println(lbt);
```

Comment: Понял. Но `36791942` - это переменная ID аккаунта, информация о котором выводится. Что в таком случае нужно в четвертой строке в скобках после `.getJsonObject`? Переменная с самим ID есть, но вариант `.getJsonObject(id)` не работает. И метода .getAsJsonObject() в GSON нет, насколько я знаю.

Comment: Обновил код, работает.